# Ordenar números de un archivo .txt en Java

Tags: java, archivo, txt, ordenar

Quisiera saber cómo ordenar números que se encuentran en un archivo .txt en Java. En mi archivo .txt tengo los siguientes números:

`2,1,4`

`7,9,8`

`5,3,1`

El código que hice se muestra a continuación tiene una ArrayList que está guardando temporalmente los números que está recibiendo de leerLinea, después de hacer eso pensé en convertir la ArrayList a una Array llamada "arrDesordenado" y seguidamente aplicar el Arrays.sort para que me ordenará mi Array, pero no la ordena.

```
package ordenarArchivos;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author VG12
 */

public class ordenarTxt {
    
    static String muestras[];
    static List <String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String arrDesordenado[];
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        
        
        try{
            
            BufferedReader Lectura = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Numeros.txt"));
            
            
            String leerLinea = Lectura.readLine();
            
            
            while(leerLinea != null){
                //ArrayList que está recibiendo los valores de leerLinea
                al.add(leerLinea);
                
                leerLinea = Lectura.readLine();
                
            }
            
            arrDesordenado = al.toArray(new String[al.size()]);
            
            Arrays.sort(arrDesordenado);
            
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los valores proporcionados por la muestra son:\n\n" + Arrays.toString(arrDesordenado));
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("El Archivo solicitado no ha sido encontrado" + e.getMessage());
        }catch(IOException IOe){
            System.out.println("El Archivo solicitado no se pudo abrir o cerrar" + IOe.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

El resultado que quiero obtener es este:

`1,2,4`

`7,8,9`

`1,3,5`

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que esta sucediendo, es que el objeto `FileReader` espera como constructor que le pases una `String` con el **path/ruta** COMPLETA del archivo que intentas leer, no solo la relativa al proyecto que estes desarrollando.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
 package com.test.sandbox;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
//IMPORTANTE ESTE IMPORT
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author VG12
 * @edited-by Fabrizio
 * @date 16/03/2021
 */

public class Test {
    
    static String muestras[];
    static List <String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String arrDesordenado[];
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        
        
        try{
            File archivo = new File("ordenar.txt");
            BufferedReader lectura = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo.getAbsolutePath()));
            
            
            String leerLinea = lectura.readLine();
            
            
            while(leerLinea != null){
                //ArrayList que está recibiendo los valores de leerLinea
                al.add(leerLinea);
                
                leerLinea = lectura.readLine();
                
            }
            
            arrDesordenado = al.toArray(new String[al.size()]);
            
            Arrays.sort(arrDesordenado);
            
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los valores proporcionados por la muestra son:\n\n" + Arrays.toString(arrDesordenado));
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            // Cuidado los espacios
            System.out.println("El Archivo solicitado no ha sido encontrado: " + e.getMessage());
        }catch(IOException IOe){
            System.out.println("El Archivo solicitado no se pudo abrir o cerrar" + IOe.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

También puedes obtener la ruta del archivo con métodos tales como:

```
File fichero = new File("Numeros.txt");
fichero.getAbsolutePath();
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

**EDIT 2:**

Cabe destacar que estas clases y metodos se encuentran desde JDK1.1

**EDIT 3:**

Quizá siga tirando error ya que la ruta completa de un archivo en un Windows OS contiene los *backslashes* (\). Para que esto sea valido tendrias que representarlo así:

**Como el método `getAbsolutePath()` te pasa la ruta:**

C:\Users\usuario\Documentos...

**Como la JVM lo interpretaría correctamente**

C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documentos\...

Esto se llama "Escapar el slash" y sirve para indicarle a la JVM que estas queriendo poner un backslash, ya que ese símbolo se usa en muchos caracteres especiales.

En cambio, si utilizas esto en un Sistema operativo Linux-like, no habria problemas con el método que te pase antes.

**EDIT 4: EJEMPLO CON RUTA ESTÁTICA**

```
BufferedReader lectura = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\project1\\src\\main\\java\\com\\test\\sandbox\\ordenar.txt"));
```

**RESULTADOS**

Archivo ordenar.txt
[image: Archivo ordenar.txt]

**RESULTADO:**

[image: RESULTADO]

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero no entendí muy bien lo del método "getAbsolutePath()" (Apenas voy iniciando en Java).

Comment: Lo que pasó es que instancié la clase `File` (o sea, la invoque). Luego la asigné en la variable `archivo`. Una vez creado el **objeto** `archivo`, accedí a la función `getAbsolutePath()` (las funciones en java se llaman métodos porque pertenecen a una clase). Ese método te devuelve una cadena de texto (`String`) que contiene la ruta completa a tu archivo de texto.

Comment: Ya entendí, muchas gracias, quisiera preguntar algo más, para ordenar los números que se encuentran en el .txt no puedo usar el **Arrays.sort** porque no funciona con los datos que tengo en mi arreglo de tipo String "arrDesordenado", me darías algún consejo para mostrar los números de manera ordenada usando algún otro método

Comment: Tienes que poner todos los números que vayas a ordenar en líneas separadas, es decir:

**ANTES:**
1. 1,2,3
2. 3,5,78


**DESPUÉS;**

1. 1
2. 2
3. 3

ETC


Es decir, cada numero en su linea separada.

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta para que veas el resultado con imagenes

Comment: Ya he actualizado la pregunta con las imágenes para que lo puedas ver, por las dudas de que me exprese mal.
Si te ayudé no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta y darle puntito ;)

Comment: Sí me has ayudado, gracias y disculpa, soy nuevo en esta página :)

Comment: Un placer ayudarte, de veras.

Comment: @AntonioLiévano si te ha ayudado por favor márcala como correcta y dale un +1.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la estructura de los datos de tu archivo si deseas ordenar los números de cada linea, puedes convertir cada linea a un array usando:

```
 String numeros[] = linea.split(",");
```

y este array ordenarlo

```
 Arrays.sort(numeros);
```

por lo cada array de numeros ordenados lo agregas a  una variable para imprimir la salida ordenada.

Este sería el  código:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        
        try{
            
            BufferedReader Lectura = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Numeros.txt"));
            

            for(String linea = Lectura.readLine(); linea != null; linea = Lectura.readLine()){
        System.out.println(linea);
                
                String numeros[] = linea.split(",");
                Arrays.sort(numeros);
                salida += Arrays.toString(numeros) + "\n";                                           
                
            }
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los valores proporcionados por la muestra son:\n\n" + salida);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("El Archivo solicitado no ha sido encontrado" + e.getMessage());
        }catch(IOException IOe){
            System.out.println("El Archivo solicitado no se pudo abrir o cerrar" + IOe.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Entrada:

```
2,1,4
7,9,8
5,3,1
```

Salida:

```
Los valores proporcionados por la muestra son:

[1, 2, 4]
[7, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: Disculpa una pregunta más, si quisiera pasar el arreglo de tipo String "arrDesordenado" a un arreglo de tipo int, ¿qué modificaría?

Comment: ahora edito la pregunta,pero es básicamente crear un array int y utilizar integer.parseInt()